# Is it worth buying a SATA III SSD while my mobo supports only SATA II?

Tags: ssd, sata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it worth to get a SATA-3 controller to max my SSD out?](https://superuser.com/questions/309966/is-it-worth-to-get-a-sata-3-controller-to-max-my-ssd-out)

After multiple thoughts I decided to buy my first SSD drive, and after some research i've found theese:

- OCZ Vertex 2

  - SATA II (3Gb/s)
  - SandForce SF1200
  - Max Read: up to 285MB/s
  - Max Write: up to 275MB/s

and

- OCZ Agility 3

  - SATA III (6Gb/s)
  - SandForce SF2281
  - Max Read: up to 525MB/s
  - Max Write: up to 475MB/s

(both of 40 GB capacity)

Agility 3 costs **only 10$** more than Vertex 2. Is it worth buying it, assuming that my motherboard supports only SATA II 3Gb/s? Can I do something to avoid the bottleneck? *(upgrading mobo is not an option)*

Comment: See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/324035/will-a-2010-macbook-pro-without-sata-iii-benefit-from-a-6-gbps-ssd/324049#324049). In short, if the price difference is really $10, you should definitely get the faster one because the controller chip is evidently better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say for 10 bucks it's worth it for future proofing and better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan an upgrade in the next year - definitely.

If not - you must check which is more stable of the two models and has lower fail rates..