# SATA 3 PCIe Controller working with decreased performance (slower than SATA 2)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, sata, pci-express

After reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/309966/is-it-worth-to-get-a-sata-3-controller-to-max-my-ssd-out/310018#310018) question about maxing out an SSD I decided to do so myself.

My [mobo](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dp55wb.html) only supports SATA 2 and has two PCIe 2.0 x1 connectors (which promiss up to 500 mb/s). So after some searching I decided to go with this [controller](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00560ZOGO/ref=pe_385721_37038051_TE_dp_1) from amazon.

My Samsung magician benchmark before upgrade (running SATA 2):

[image]

Now after installing the controller all of the benchmark scores are lower (even though the Samsung Magician app confirms its connected to a SATA 3 port):

[image]

**What can I do to remedy this?**
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The controller you bought doesn't promise 600 MB/sec transfer rates it promises transfers rates up to that. I quote "transfer rate up of 600 MB" there is a huge difference.  How many times did you run this test?  Have you made sure your using the current firmware?

Comment: I've ran the test twice, both tests yielded similar results. I am using the current firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SATA ports on your motherboard are wired into a PCIe 2.0 lane, which allows up to 500 MB/sec (which is shared among all six of its SATA 2 ports).

In looking at the specs for that card, I found the following:

```
Compliant with PCI Express Specification 1.0a. Design for PCIE 1x
```

The PCIe 1.0 spec only allowed for 250 MB/sec per lane.  Minus the 20% protocol overhead, you're looking at only ~200 MB/Sec.  Your SSD is pegging that card to its limits.

Basically, the card you bought is a cheap no-name card whose advertised specs are misleading.  Even though the SATA 3 controller is faster than the one on your mobo, they wired it to a bridge chip that is far slower and then advertised a spec that the card cannot physically achieve.